# Why is the neutron electric dipole term CP violating?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, neutrons, dipole, cp-violation

I have heard that a term of the form $\bar{q}\sigma^{\mu\nu}q F_{\mu\nu}$ is CP violating but looking at any Textbook (e.g. Peskin Schröder) one can see that the CP transformations are the following:

$\begin{align}CP&: \bar{q}\sigma^{\mu\nu}q\rightarrow -\eta(\mu)\eta(\nu)\bar{q}\sigma^{\mu\nu}q\\
CP&: F^{\mu\nu}\rightarrow -\eta(\mu)\eta(\nu)F^{\mu\nu}\end{align}$

Where $\eta(\mu)$ is $1$ for $\mu=0$ and $(-1)$ for $\mu>0$. So overall all factors should cancel. Why does this term supposed to violate CP?

Comment: Are you *positive* you have not skipped a $\gamma_5$ from your "heard" term, or, equivalently a tilde above the *F* ? You just wrote down a Pauli moment...

Comment: Ah ok my bad. Then the CP violating term is with the $\gamma^5$ in the bilinear spinor tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term $\bar{q}\sigma^{\mu\nu}q F_{\mu\nu}$ is **not** CP-violating. The expressions in the OP are both correct, and they correctly show that the magnetic term is CP-symmetric.

Note for example that QED (which is manifestly C, P, and T symmetric), generates a non-zero result for the effective Pauli term $\bar{q}\sigma^{\mu\nu}q F_{\mu\nu}$. This is the famous Schwinger calculation, which gives the corrections to the **magnetic** moment of leptons, $\delta a=\alpha/\pi+\mathcal O(\alpha^2)$. Perhaps you had in mind the **electric** moment instead?

Comment: Ah ok Thank you so the CP violating term would be $\bar{q} \sigma^{\mu\nu}\gamma^5 q F_{\mu\nu}$, which must not be present for QED due to CP conservation?

Comment: @krabbypatty Ye.